# Jquery/JS not loading text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I am writing a word/name generator. On my local computer the script works fine but when uploaded, the jQuery is not able to load the text file and I get a 404 not found error. The text file is there, I have checked a number of times. Here is the simplified code: http://namepicker.site11.com/test.html

Thank you for any advise,
Todd

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery-Load Text File</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadXML()
            {
                var file= './names/names.txt';
                $.get(file, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            }
            </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="loadXML();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing that can be solved here. You must not have uploaded the file to the correct place or with the correct name. Double check this!

Comment: I think there's something odd going on here. If you go to http://namepicker.site11.com/names/names.txt, the response is a 404. However, if you go to http://namepicker.site11.com/names/wrong-file.txt, it redirects you to a 404 on your web host. You'll have to check what's going on with them (unless, as pimvdb suggests, it's an underlying script)

Comment: The file is there: http://namepicker.site11.com/names, and the permissions are correct. So what crazy thing could block access to a simple text file?

Comment: Looks like youve renamed the files and they are working? Thats very odd. Your host must block .txt files ..

Comment: Yes, very odd indeed, never run across a host that blocks .txt files. But with the shared servers who knows what to expect sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://namepicker.site11.com/names/names.txt

The file does not exist, It needs to be there to be loaded. Try creating it and see if your having the same issues.

EDIT:
http://namepicker.site11.com/names/

File does seem to exist, perhaps check the CHMOD settings on the files.

Comment: Do you have similar problems inside of other directories?

Comment: I did just duplicate the names directory and renamed it and same issue.

Comment: Well It would seem that its a problem with your webhost. Do you have some sort of control panel you can manage access from? Past that there isn't much people on here can help you with. Perhaps check your htaccess but other than that I think you'll need to contact your web host.

Comment: That is the problem. My server does not allow .txt files. New one to me. I changed the extension to .NPtxt and everything works as expected. Thank you for leading me to that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well a simple look at Chrome's Developer Tools reveals this error:

```
GET http://namepicker.site11.com/names/names.txt 404 (Not Found)
```

Obviously, you'd need to actually upload the `names.txt` file into the `names` directory.

Edit: I see that other files redirect to your hosting 404 page while `names/names.txt` does not, so perhaps it exists but does it somehow still send a 404 code. Is it a real text file or an underlying PHP file?

Comment: How strange .. It apears in http://namepicker.site11.com/names/ but none of the files listed there seem to work. Something is blocking access.

Comment: That is the problem. What would cause this? The file is indeed there and the permissions are correct.

Comment: @maddogandnoriko: Do you have a `.htaccess` file somewhere? What if you upload another kind of file?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not ready yet. You need to [wrap jQuery functions](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function()
        var file= './names/names.txt';
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: He is not interacting with the dom at that point and anyway he uses body onload to kick off his js

Comment: Yes, very true. I need more coffee.

Comment: Technically jQuery is ready, it's the DOM that's not ready. But yeah, since he's calling the function with an onload event in the <body> tag I think you're right.  Either wrap with $(function(){ ... }); or for testing purposes, take the work out of the function. This way jQuery will load the file and alert it's contents. Since $.get isn't waiting on any DOM elements, that would show you if your paths are correct. EDIT: I need more coffee too. See Redsquare's comment.  :)

Comment: @redsquare - I know, that's the point I was trying to make. I glossed over the fact that calling the function in onready was the same as wrapping in $(function(){}); - anyway, that's why I was suggesting removing the work from the function - because xhr doesn't require dom ready.

Comment: You can see the problem without the JS/jQuery by going directly to http://namepicker.site11.com/names/ and see the files are there, but they will not load any text.